# Как вывести каждый 7 элемент синим

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
<div id="f1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=[];
for (var i = 1; i <366; i++) {
    a.push(' '+i+' ');



    }
    if(a[i]%7==0){
        document.getElementById('f1').style.color='Blue';
    }

    console.log(a);
    document.getElementById('f1').innerHTML=a;

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < 366; i++) {
    a.push(" " + i + " ");
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = i;
    if (i % 7 === 0) {
      div.style.color = "blue";
    }
    document.getElementById('f1').appendChild(div);
  }
```

```html
  <div id="f1"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var a = [];

for (var i = 1; i < 366; i++) {
 a.push('<span style="color:' + (i % 7 ? 'black' : 'blue') + '">' + i + '</span>');
}

document.getElementById('f1').innerHTML = a.join(", ");
```

```html
<div id="f1"></div>
```

Comment: Ничего себе подход. Может ещё `eval` используете? Создавать элемент в виде строки, чтобы потом вставлять эту строку в вёрстку это плохая идея.

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach если скрипт выполняет поставленную задачу, то имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: @UModeL да ладно? Повторюсь, может тогда евал использовать тоже нормально?